# maven release:branch - where to perform?

Tags: maven

I tried today to switch our release build so that it uses branches. Before my change, I just did

```
mvn release:prepare -B -Dusername=$SVN_USER -Dpassword=$SVN_PASSWORD -Dtag=$RELEASE_VERSION -DreleaseVersion=$RELEASE_VERSION -DdevelopmentVersion=$NEXT_DEV_VERSION
mvn release:perform
```

Now I changed to use

```
mvn release:branch -B -Dusername=$SVN_USER -Dpassword=$SVN_PASSWORD -DbranchName=$RELEASE_VERSION -DreleaseVersion=$RELEASE_VERSION -DdevelopmentVersion=$NEXT_DEV_VERSION -DautoVersionSubmodules=true -DbranchBase=$SVN_BRANCH_BASE -DdryRun=false -DsuppressCommitBeforeBranch=false -DremoteTagging=false -DupdateBranchVersions=true -DupdateVersionsToSnapshot=false -DupdateWorkingCopyVersions=true -DgenerateBackupPoms=false
```

then I checked that branch out and tried to perform a release on it. But this does not work, it tells me:
    Unable to configure SCM repository: No such provider: 's'

SCM config is:

```
<scm>
<connection>scm:svn:https://svn2.mycompany.com:8443/svn/polyalert/branches/02_Los_1/releases/0.01.9</connection>
<developerConnection>scm:svn:https://svn2.cmycompany.com:8443/svn/polyalert/branches/02_Los_1/releases/0.01.9</developerConnection>
<url>https://svn2.mycompany.com:8443/svn/polyalert/branches/02_Los_1/releases/0.01.9</url>
</scm>
```

This url might look a bit strange, but we do not have a default layout and this is a correct branch URL.

This is done with maven 3. I´m not sure if it´s correct to do the release:perform in another location than I did the release:branch, but I don´t have a better idea, specifically because I can not set any release.properties file like it is created with release:prepare. Or would it be necessary to do the release:branch AND the release:prepare? A first try on that did not work and got the same error.

Any suggestions?

Thanks
Michael

Comment: Ok, specifically in my case, I found out that there has really been a misconfigured SCM URL in the root pom in the trunk. It made me wonder, because the shown root pom scm entry of the branch is correct, but this was on of the problems in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After lots of struggle, I found the following approach working:

- Ensure that your trunk has definitely correct scm info in the pom.
- run `mvn release:branch -B -Dusername=$SVN_USER -Dpassword=$SVN_PASSWORD -DbranchName=$RELEASE_VERSION -DreleaseVersion=$RELEASE_VERSION -DdevelopmentVersion=$NEXT_DEV_VERSION -DautoVersionSubmodules=true -DbranchBase=$SVN_BRANCH_BASE -DupdateWorkingCopyVersions=true`.
  This will create a branch in SVN where all versions are kept like they are in the trunk and will then increase version number in the trunk to $NEXT_DEV_VERSION and commit this as well. Branchbase can be set in the plugin configuration as well (in this case it can be omitted here).
- checkout the new-made branch and change into the local branch dir
- run `mvn release:prepare -B -Dusername=$SVN_USER -Dpassword=$SVN_PASSWORD -Dtag=$RELEASE_VERSION -DreleaseVersion=$RELEASE_VERSION` to update the release number in your branch to $RELEASE_VERSION (will be changed locally + commit into the branch by this single command). This command will on top create a release tag.
- run `mvn release:perform` in your local branch dir to start the actual build. This will checkout the tag created in the previous step and build upon this code.